# Is it possible to call a dialog with a different attribute that have been initialized with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to list a punch of items using PHP in WordPress giving each of them a dialog with the same class but different IDs. I want to initialize the dialog using the class that I gave them but when I want to open the dialog I want to use the ID
I tried this:

```html
 <div class="delete-dialog" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
   <div class="deleteBtn">
     <button id="closeDeleteDialogBtn">
       <span class="dashicons dashicons-no"></span>
     </button>
   </div>
   <div class="message">
     <p>this is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="dialogBtns">
     <button class="button button-primary confirmDeleteBtn">Delete</button>
     <button class="button button-primary cancelDeleteBtn">Cancel</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And in jQuery I did the following:

```js
$('.delete-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    model: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    show: {
        effect: 'blind',
        duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'explode',
        duration: 500
    }
}).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();

$('.deleteBtn #closeDeleteDialogBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = $($(e.target).parent()).parent().attr('id');
    $('.delete-dialog#'+id).dialog('close');
    console.log('hid');
});

$('.confirmDeleteBtn').click(function () {
    console.log('confirmed');
})

$('.cancelDeleteBtn').click(function (e) {
    let id = $($(e.target).parent()).parent().attr('id');
    $('.delete-dialog#'+id).dialog('close')
})

$('.delete-btn').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault()
    let id = $(e.target).closest('li').attr('id');
    $('.delete-dialog').dialog('open');
    console.log($(".delete-dialog").attr('id'));
});
```

Knowing that I get no errors no all is good even with the dialog it just no showing that's the only problem so I figured it's the attribute because when I call it only with the class it shows up when add the id to the class nothing show up, but using the class only will cause all the dialogs with the same class to show up

Comment: Yes, you can attach an event listener using a class and then use the element's id to reference the element.  If it's not working with the id, try debugging. Does the rendered HTML of the element show the id you expect? And when you console.log the id in JavaScript, do you get the result you expect? Also, exactly what part of your code is not working?

Comment: @devlincarnate i tried what you said the debugging returns the id correctly as well as the rendered HTML but the rendered html get wrapped up in a jquery element so my element become a child not a parent

Comment: `id="<?php the_ID(); ?>"` - that's going to create a purely numeric ID - and while those _are_ allowed in HTML5, you can't directly use them in a selector, without additional escaping (https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) Add a static, non-numeric prefix to those IDs to avoid this kind of trouble.

Comment: i did the same thing with the ID and all but i took the dialog out of the loop so that would only one loop and that fixed the problem and i added the clicked button li id in the dialog data so i can know which item is being licked.
Sorry i didn't provide you guys with the whole context